# How to implement rxjs zip operator for array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a source that gives an array of arrays. All arrays has the same number of element(s).
How can I use rxjs zip operator to transform the source array as described below so I could easily do the mapping? Thanks in advance!

```
var source = Rx.Observable.from([[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"], ["do", "re", "mi"]]);
// I would like to transform to:
// [[1, "a", "do"], [2, "b", "re"], [3, "c", "mi"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each array to an Observable, then zip:

```
var myArrays = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['do', 're', 'mi']
];

var myObservables = myArrays.map(xs => Rx.Observable.from(xs));
var zipped$ = Rx.Observable.zip(myObservables);

zipped$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Alternatively, you can forego the conversion from `Array` to `Observable` and use lodash's `zip` to combine the arrays:

```
var zipped = _.zip(...myArrays)
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin! 
Following rxjs example on autocomplete [link](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete.js), I get it working using lodash this way: 
`searcher.subscribe(function (data) { var zipped = _.zip(data[1], data[2], data[3]); // ... });`
But, this is after subscription already. 
How can I zip it before subscription? Maybe somewhere during _searcher_ declaration: 
`var searcher = keyup.flatMapLatest(searchWikipedia).zip(...)`

Comment: You can perform a `map`:  `var zipped = searcher.map(data => _.zip(data[0], data[1], data[2]);`

Comment: Ah ok, got it! It seems that instead of rxjs zip operator, I just have to use array zip function (like from lodash). Just for clarity: your code should be written like this: `var zipped = searcher.map(data => _.zip(data[1], data[2], data[3]);` since data[0] from wikipedia api is a string and the next 3 elements are arrays of titles, short descriptions and links.
Thanks!